# Sort data frames in list by alphabetical order

Tags: r

I would like to know how to sort data frames in a list.

```
xf1b <- data.frame(c(7,5,3,4,5), c(43,56,23,78,89))    
cf2b <- data.frame(c(7,5,3,4,6), c(43,56,24,48,89))    
df3b <- data.frame(c(7,5,3,4,5), c(43,56,23,78,89)) 

colnames(xf1b) <- c("xVar1","xVar2")    
colnames(cf2b) <- c("yVar1","yVar2")    
colnames(df3b) <- c("zVar1","zVar2")

a2 <- list(xf1b,cf2b,df3b)    
names(a2) <- c("XYZ","DEC","CED")
```

How can I sort `a2` by alphabetical order?

Comment: Do you need to sort the `list` or the data.frame within the list.  If it is the latter, it is already sorted by the column names.

Answer (score 2):

We can `order` on the `names` of 'a2'

```
a2[order(names(a2))]
```

If it is the order of `data.frame` within the `list`

```
lapply(a2, function(x) x[order(names(x))])
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(a2, ~ .x %>%
             select(sort(names(.))))
```

If it is to keep the 'Var1' and 'Var2' columns together

```
bind_cols(a2) %>% 
     split.default(., substring(names(.), 2))
```